# Show git diff on file in staging area

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stage

Is there a way I can see the changes that were made to a `file` after I have done `git add file`?

That is, when I do:

```
git add file
git diff file
```

no diff is shown. I guess there's a way to see the differences since the last commit but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1859, accepted):

You can show changes that have been staged with the `--cached` flag:

```
$ git diff --cached
```

In more recent versions of git, you can also use the `--staged` flag (`--staged` is a synonym for `--cached`):

```
$ git diff --staged
```

Comment: Is there a way to use difftool (i.e. DiffMerge) to show this result?

Comment: @Terry: Yes, `difftool` accepts most of the same flags as `diff`.

Comment: `--staged` is a much better name indeed for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 201):

In order to see the changes that have been staged already, you can pass the `-–staged` option to `git diff` (in pre-1.6 versions of Git, use `–-cached`).

```
git diff --staged
git diff --cached
```

Answer (score 76):

You can also use `git diff HEAD file` to show the diff for a specific file.

See the `EXAMPLE` section under [`git-diff(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: This shows both the diffs in the staged and non-staged files. This is what I was looking for. Thanks